# JQuery form validation format for bootstrap time picker

Tags: php, jquery, html, validation

Hello,
        
        I am Use Bootstrap DateTimePicker, You Can Show My Plugin By [Click Here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker),
        
        The Actual Problem With This Plugin Is in Form Validation..
        It's Come With Textbox, So Any Use Can Type Any Thing Which Is Not In Form Of DATE & TIME WITH AM/PM.
So Please Any One Can Tell Me Systex Of This Plugin Format For JQuery Form Validation.

Answer (score 0):

here is the just example for the format of d-mm-yyy

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.validator.addMethod(
"australianDate",
function(value, element) {
    // put your own logic here, this is just a (crappy) example
    return value.match(/^\d\d?\-\d\d?\-\d\d\d\d$/);
},
"Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy."
 );
var $validator = $("#addform_free").validate({
      rules: {
        prefer_date:{
            australianDate : true
        },
    }
    });

    });
    </script>
  <input type="text" required="" id="prefer_date" name="prefer_date" class="form-control hasDatepicker valid" placeholder="" value="16-04-2016">
```